# How can I get top 10 frequently(trending) asked question from QnA maker on daily basis?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search, azure-qna-maker

I am trying to understand how can I use my QnA maker to know the top 10 trending or frequently asked questions from my knowledge base? Is there any parameter or metadata keys are being use in QnA for storing the frequency of questions? Is azure search can help here anything? Please suggest...

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named “What topics can I ask about here?” and “What types of questions should I avoid asking?”. And more importantly, please read the Stack Overflow question checklist. You might also want to learn about Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples

Comment: This is quite a broad question, for which there doesn't exist a solution out-of-the-box. There currently isn't a mechanism to retrieve the top queries asked for your QnA maker's knowledge base. You can make use of search traffic analytics: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-traffic-analytics to identify and log search events made against the search service backing the QnA maker knowledge base, but this might only identify question fragments/keywords and not the entire question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following on from Mick's answer, assuming that you have Application Insights enabled for your bot's QnA Cognitive Service then you can use one of the queries below once you have navigated to the [Analytics page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/get-analytics-knowledge-base) (as detailed by Mick):

They may not be the most performant or optimised queries as I just hacked up the sample ones until I got what I wanted.

```
// top questions in last 48 hours
requests
| where url endswith "generateAnswer" and timestamp > ago(48h) 
| project timestamp, id, name, resultCode, duration
| parse kind = regex name with *"(?i)knowledgebases/"KbId"/generateAnswer"
| join kind= inner (
traces | extend id = operation_ParentId
) on id
| extend question = tostring(customDimensions['Question'])
| summarize Count=count() by question
| top 100 by Count 
| project question, Count 


// top questions since timestamp
requests
| where url endswith "generateAnswer" and timestamp > datetime('2019-05-12 00:00:00')  
| project timestamp, id, name, resultCode, duration
| parse kind = regex name with *"(?i)knowledgebases/"KbId"/generateAnswer"
| join kind= inner (
traces | extend id = operation_ParentId
) on id
| extend question = tostring(customDimensions['Question'])
| summarize Count=count() by question
| top 100 by Count 
| project question, Count 


// top questions of all time
requests
| where url endswith "generateAnswer"  
| project timestamp, id, name, resultCode, duration
| parse kind = regex name with *"(?i)knowledgebases/"KbId"/generateAnswer"
| join kind= inner (
traces | extend id = operation_ParentId
) on id
| extend question = tostring(customDimensions['Question'])
| summarize Count=count() by question
| top 100 by Count 
| project question, Count
```

As a bonus you can click on the chart button to view the information as a chart once the query has been run.

Comment: Yes, we can. Thanks for it.

Answer (score 1):

QnA Maker stores all chat logs and other telemetry, if you have enabled App Insights during the creation of your QnA Maker service. On [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/get-analytics-knowledge-base) you can find sample queries to get your chat logs from App Insights.

**Sample query**

```
    requests
    | where url endswith "generateAnswer"
    | project timestamp, id, name, resultCode, duration
    | parse kind = regex name with *"(?i)knowledgebases/"KbId"/generateAnswer"
    | join kind= inner (
    traces | extend id = operation_ParentId
    ) on id
    | extend question = tostring(customDimensions['Question'])
    | extend answer = tostring(customDimensions['Answer'])
    | project KbId, timestamp, resultCode, duration, question, answer
```

You can write a custom query to retrieve your top 10 frequently asked questions / given answers.

Comment: Thanks Mick... it's really helpful but could you please suggest how we can get metadata details

Comment: What kind of metadata details do you want to retrieve?